# Can't Create RollingFileAppender with System property variable

Tags: java, log4j2

While creating RollingFileAppender with a System property variable I got the following error.

```
ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:566)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:582)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:217)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:551)
at com.hifx.lens.services.AvroSerializerFactory.<init>(AvroSerializerFactory.java:16)
at com.hifx.lens.services.AvroSerializerFactory.init(AvroSerializerFactory.java:43)
at com.hifx.lens.Accumulo.main(Accumulo.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:103)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:191)
... 27 more
```

My log4j2.yml configuration file is

```
    Configutation:
    name: Default
    Properties:
        Property:
          name: LOG_PATH
          value: "logs"
      Appenders:
        Console:
          name: Console_Appender
          target: SYSTEM_OUT
          PatternLayout:
            pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
    File:
      name: File_Appender
      fileName: ${sys:LOG_PATH}/log.log
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

    RollingFile:
      name: RollingFile_Appender
      fileName: ${sys:LOG_PATH}/log.log
      filePattern: "logs/archive/rollingfile.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz"
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
      Policies:
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          size: 100 KB
      DefaultRollOverStrategy:
        max: 30

  Loggers:
    Root:
      level: debug
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: RollingFile_Appender

    Logger:
          - name: Accumulo_File_logger
            level: debug
            AppenderRef:
              - ref: File_Appender
```

If I change the filename of RollingFile_Appender to using property name ie:

```
fileName: ${LOG_PATH}/log.log
```

then the error is disappeared and everything working fine.

If I use the File_Appender( which is also using the same System property variable(sys:LOG_PATH)) then also everything working fine.

Same error if I change sys: to env:
I think there is some parsing issue with the jackson.
I need to configure the log path from environment variables.

Dependencies using are

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Somebody please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you defined both File_Appender and RollingFile_Appender to log into the same file. They kind of "own" their log files, so once a File appender has been created for the `${sys:LOG_PATH}/log.log` you cannot create a RollingFile appender pointing to the same file. The second appender in the configuration file tries to create a LogManager that would be responsible for the file, finds the first one being already there so tries to cast into the class that it needs - and fails.

If you move the RollingFile_Appender above File_Appender the exception will be:

```
main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender for element File. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Now the RollingFile_Appender would own the `${sys:LOG_PATH}/log.log` file and you wouldn't be able to create the File_Appender because of the same reason.

Solution: remove one of the appenders, having both at the same time doesn't make sense anyway - they would have to compete with each other, or point each of the to a different file.